# suggestion on how to read a large file to jtextarea

Tags: java, swing, file, jtextarea

I want to read large file like 10-15k lines to jtextarea.
Beside that, I also have to add every line to List and to highlight some specific lines in jtextarea.

What I tried for now is, I pass file into FileReader into BufferedReader. Inside my SwingWorker, in doBackground method I call:

```
 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      textArea.append(line);
      textArea.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
      list.add(line);
      highlightLine(lineNumber);
 }
```

When I run the program, and I choose file and open read process, it instantly loads up to 700 lines, then program slows down and loads like 10 lines per second.

Another idea I have is to, read a whole file with JTextComponent read method (which seems to setText faster then append every line), and then, read again whole file or iterate through every line in jtextarea and add that line to List and also highlight, which I think is not very efficient. What do you suggest me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to read large file like 10-15k lines to jtextarea

Use the `read(...)` method of the `JTextArea` class to read the entire file directly into the text area.

> I also have to add every line to List

Why do you need two copies of the text? If you need a line of data you can get the text from the text area:

```
int start = textArea.getLineStartOffset(...);
int end = textArea.getLineEndOffset(...);
String text = textArea.getDocument().getText(...);
```

> to highlight some specific lines

Use a Highlighter to highlight the lines after they have been loaded into the text area.

```
Highlighter highlighter = textArea.getHighlighter();
highlighter.addHighlight(...);
```

Again you can get the offsets of the line using code from above.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html) interface. it is the model that holds the data of the view-component that is `JTextArea`. You can get it from `JTextArea` with `getDocument` or you can use one of the classes that already implement `Document`: AbstractDocument, DefaultStyledDocument, HTMLDocument, PlainDocument. Then add your `Document` of choice to `JTextArea` with `setDocument`.

You can use `insertString(int offset, String str, AttributeSet a)` to add content to the `Document`. It also supports several listeners and you could consider a using `render(Runnable r)` to style it the document.

Comment: I will test your idea by tommorow. Thank you on the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but I would suggest putting all the file contents into a String, then use the setText(String text) method to set the text of the JTextArea all at once.